# Application of Fermat's little theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Question: Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes and let $n=pq$.  Prove that if $a=p+n\mathbb{Z}$ and $b=q+n\mathbb{Z}$, then $a^{q-1}+b^{p-1}=1.$

I'm not entirely convinced that the above is true.  I have applied Fermat's little theorem.  Since $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes - $a^{q-1}\equiv 1 \pmod q$ and $b^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p.$  Where I am getting stuck is how to apply that second given: $a=p+n\mathbb{Z}$ and $b=q+n\mathbb{Z}.$

Added due to player3236:
$a^{q-1}+b^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod q$ since $b^{q-1}\equiv 0\pmod q$.  Similarly for $a$ and $p$.  This shows that $a^{q-1}+b^{p-1}-1\equiv 0 \pmod {pq}$,or that $a^{q-1}+b^{p-1}-1$ is divisible by $pq$ since $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

Comment: What are $a^{q-1} \pmod p$ and $b^{p-1} \pmod q$? And by extension, what are $a^{q-1}+b^{p-1} \pmod {p } \text{ and }\pmod q$?

Comment: $a$ is a coset in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. How is $a^{q-1}$ then meant?

Comment: @player3236 I edited my question to address what you mentioned.  I didn't feel comfortable typing that amount of LaTeX without seeing it in real time.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Did you intend to claim that $p^{q-1}+q^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$?    You wrote that it should equal $1$ which, as has been remarked, does not make sense.

Comment: Well, since you have shown that $a^{q-1} + b^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$, you proved what the question asked for.

Comment: Emka, I said that $a=p+n\Bbb Z$ is a set of numbers, namely $\{\cdots ,-2n+p,-n+p.p,p+n,p+2n,\cdots\}$. What is a power of a set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well  $a \equiv p\pmod q$ and $b\equiv q\equiv 0 \pmod q$ so $a^{q-1}+b^{p-1}\equiv p^{q-1}\equiv 1 \pmod q$.

Likewise $a\equiv p\equiv 0\pmod p$ and $b\equiv q\pmod p$ so  $a^{q-1}+b^{p-1}\equiv q^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Now by Chinese Remainder theorem we know any mutual solution $a^{q-1}+b^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $a^{q-1}+b^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod q$ is unique $\mod pq$.  And $a^{q-1} + b^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$ is a solution.  So it is the only solution.